# Sqlalchemy inheritance - delete child row without deleting the parent row?

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }
class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    engineer_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
    }

e = Engineer()
session.add(e)
session.commit()
```

Creating an object of Engineer will add a row in both employee and engineer table.

```
session.delete(e)
session.commit()
```

Now when I delete the engineer object I want to only remove the row in engineer table and not in the employee table. How do I achieve this? Right now the rows in both table gets removed.

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

If you delete the engineer object using the ORM (by calling `session.delete(obj)`), then it **will** delete records from both tables.

However, what you want may be accomplished by

```
session.query(Engineer).filter(Engineer.id==e.id).delete()
session.commit()
```